# Android UiAutomator: does UiObject have a .getClassName() method?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

According to the documentation, the `UiObject` class has a method function `.getClassName()` that should return the `className` property of the UI object.  Link:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiObject.html#getClassName()

However, when I try to build my UIAutomator tests, the build fails with this error message:

```
[javac] /Users/shastings/devel/my_project/tests/src/com/dts/test/ui/MyTest.java:55: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : method getClassName()
[javac] location: class com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject
[javac]         name = o.getClassName();
[javac]                 ^
[javac] 1 error
```

Other method functions such as `.getVisibleBounds()` work fine, and anyway the error message confirms that `o` is an instance of `UiObject`.

P.S. I just updated my SDK to the latest and this still happens.

Comment: @Anders, please put that as an answer and I will accept it.  That was the problem.

Comment: Ok no problem, moved now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getClassName()` was added in API level 18 (Android 4.3). Are you sure you are building with that version?